# How and why did Weierstrass $\wp$ get its special symbol?

Tags: complex-analysis, notation, math-history

I kind of always hated drawing the Weierstrass $\wp$ symbol by hand, and it struck me as odd how and why it achieved its special status in the first place. After all, there are tons of other important functions throughout different areas of math, but very few (if any) get special symbols; even in complex analysis, other functions, e.g., Riemann $\zeta$, are more famous than $\wp$. (I'm not very deep into complex analysis so I can't claim that $\wp$ is necessarily less important than $\zeta$.)

Could anyone please provide a bit of historical notes on Weierstrass $\wp$? A quick Google search yields a [Google Books result](http://books.google.com/books?id=RUz1Us2UDh4C&pg=PA274&lpg=PA274&dq=weierstrass+p+function+history&source=bl&ots=qRqKTpA5v7&sig=_7otpnhzsbvzkfYwpld18NIKT_o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VayWU92pK4v9oATTgoKoCQ&ved=0CH0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=weierstrass%20p%20function%20history&f=false), but the account is woefully short and doesn't seem to explain anything.

Comment: Note that $\zeta$ is an actual letter in a particular language (Greek, in this case). So it's not comparable to $\wp$ which is just a typographical change of an English letter. Also, historically I believe the $\zeta$ function was first of Euler, but Riemann did so much with it that he "gained ownership" -- but I might be mistaken here. (And send my regards to Kevin.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, it's exactly the typographical change that is weird; it's regular practice to borrow letters from Greek, and I won't call Greek letters special symbols. (And btw, $\wp$ should be a play on the German letter, since Weierstrass is German...)

Comment: German already has its "play" with fraktur fonts. Let's settle on Latin.

Comment: It's basically a cursive / script p.

Comment: @FUZxxl But it's a special script, and has its own Unicode, `\wp`, etc.

Comment: It's basically a handwritten Fraktur p. Look up, say, Kurrentschrift or Sütterlin.

Comment: *Why did Weierstrass $\wp$ get its special symbol?* - Because $\wp$ is s$\wp$ecial. :-)

Comment: @ZhenLin This question is not about how to draw the symbol, or the typographical origin. In simplest terms: why not simply a Fraktur p? Why did people adopt it despite all the inconvenience (especially in the digital age, though that's only remotely related)?

Comment: Perhaps Weierstraß was also a penmanship teacher?

Comment: Also, apparently Emmy Noether used $\mathfrak p$ (in German handwriting) instead of $\wp$ since she never knew how to draw it. [Fraktur chart](http://jri-poland.org/german1.gif) (There are many German handwritings, but the "p" is always roughly the same, though sometimes not closed on the bottom.)

Answer (score 1):

this situation is most likely analogous to how the integral symbol garnered it's affection from others. It was just simply appealing in a subjective way. I would be willing to say part of the love of mathematics is 'how cool the symbols look'. Magical thinking. I would bet it's more of a psychological and sociological phenomenon than anything of significance.

Comment: Maybe. I should start to design cool symbols.

Comment: @ksh I think the Bourbaki group invented $\varnothing$ for the empty set.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I have to say that's pretty lame. Especially in TeX, where both \emptyset and \varnothing look awful. (To be more precise, I should say in Computer Modern.)